# 9-axis IMU for weighing on a boat with varying sea conditions

Tags: imu, accuracy, gravity

I am brainstorming on how to do relatively accurate weighing scale for fish on a boat under different seastate conditions.

I know other companies use a second load cell together with calibration data and some heavy math to do the same with sucess. The issue with this is that it takes some time to compute the sample data to estimate the G-force used to compute the weight.

To me the obvious choice would be to get a 9-axis IMU together with a loadcell to counter the G-forces to get accurate measurements. If the IMU delivers an accurate G-force I would not have to consider the above solution.

- What accuracy can I expect from a high grade 9 axis IMU?
- Is a good IMU the way to go about solving this problem?

My budget is around 2000USD per item.

Comment: How is a load cell used to weigh a boat? A load cell is basically just a scale. I don't see how it can be on the boat itself which it would have to be to work on the open water

Comment: @DKNguyen I think the question is about weighing some object onboard the boat, rather than the boat itself. The problem being that the movement of the weighing system due to the movement of the boat means that you can't directly translate force on the load cell to actual mass.

Comment: Measurement time and filtering are also variables

Comment: @DKNguyen Actually weighing the boat might be an easier problem, as you can get a pretty good estimation from how deep in the water the boat is.

Comment: Oh, I think you may be correct Yeah I was thinking why wouldn't you just use the water line? Can you just not use two matched load cells where one has a known proof mass attached to it?

Comment: @DKNguyen exactly but I think the OP believes that will take too much processing (as per what he alludes to in the question).

Comment: If that is the traditional method OP is describing that takes a long time I don't see why it would be computation heavy. Wouldn't it just be a scaling multiplication? My guess is the time is not due to computation but getting a stable reading on the load cell. That said, it's actually not clear in my mind why it would take a long time to get a stable reading though since you have a proof mass and an instant reading for it at that moment.

Comment: A fishing boat scale perhaps. How many milli-g’s on boat? Lowest swell frequency?

Comment: Yes @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 you are correct. Its a fishing scale. The reason for the heavy math is that in order for the processor to compute a stabile weight it has to do a lot of samples to estimage the g forces. It uses these together with some calibration data to compute the weight. When i say long time im talking around ,5 to 1 second. Im expecting a max of 0 to 1,5 G on an axis and a minimum swell frequency of 0,1Hz. 10Seconds between each period.

Comment: I'm having trouble believing it takes at least .5 sec to process a sample. What's the setup?

Comment: Its not a single sample. Its a lot of samples that is needed to estimete the G-force. The goal is to only sample once.